# Retrieving id from a row that I've just written to the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I retrieve an `id` from a row that I've just written to the database?

Basically, I have a function in my ASP.NET a booking form that needs to write to two tables, but I need the id from what's been written in table 1, to also be store in table 2.

So:

1. write to `table 1`
2. retrieve `id` from `table 1`
3. write to `table 2`

How can I achieve this?

Regards
Tea

Comment: What database are we talking about?

Comment: Are you using Identity column for you column id ?

Comment: It's a SQL Server 2008.  But I am using insert in my ASP.NET code, no stored procedure.

Comment: If you don't want to use store procedure then select the max id from the where you have inserted value. and then insert into other tables. Which is  a bad practice. I have seen this is possible in php mysql but never seen in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asp.Net with a Sql 2008 server, you can use the **[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)** function like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Table1 (id_field) 
                OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                VALUES (...)";
```

OR

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Table1 (...) VALUES (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ";
```

In the last example, notice I'm performing an INSERT and then a SELECT in the same request...

And to get the identity use:

```
int lastId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek - Yes it will

Comment: does this replace my cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **SQL Server** use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ...

DECLARE @RecordID int = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Table2 ... VALUES (@RecordID....)
```

---

Without using stored procedures, you could attach a `SELECT` statement to the end of your SQL:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table 1 ...... ; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
int recordId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```